# Map polyline,stop Drawing

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Google maps version : 3.37.1
Test model：
     iphoneX ,IOS 12.4
     honor magic2 ,android 9.0

click buttons to change date and draw the map

step:
1.click "point1" ->"point2"->"point3"->"point2"
2.the map will stop drawing. 

We tried on Chrome's Toggle device toolbar to simulate mobile devices, it works.We also found out if we reduce the map display area, this issue won't happen so frequently. By now, we set the map showing full screen on mobile device, but the issues  present on iOS more frequent then on Android.

```
    var googleMap,
        googleMapLoaded,
        markers = [];

    var point1 = [{
        lat: "39.90419989999999",
        lng: "116.4073963",
        name: 1
    }, {
        lat: "47.790148349999996",
        lng: "64.48786675",
        name: 2
    }, {
        lat: "55.6760968",
        lng: "12.5683372",
        name: 3
    }]
    var point2 = [{
        lat: "55.6760968",
        lng: "12.5683372",
        color: "#FF0000",
        name: 4
    }, {
        lat: "41.38506389999999",
        lng: "2.1734035",
        color: "#FF0000",
        name: 5
    }, {
        lat: "41.90278349999999",
        lng: "12.4963655",
        color: "#FF0000",
        name: 6
    }, {
        lat: "47.497912",
        lng: "19.040235",
        color: "#FF0000",
        name: 7
    }, {
        lat: "50.0755381",
        lng: "14.4378005",
        color: "#FF0000",
        name: 8
    }]
    var point3 = [{
        lat: "47.6062095",
        lng: "-122.3320708",
        color: "#FF0000",
        name: 85
    }, {
        lat: "48.5342662",
        lng: "-123.0171242",
        color: "#FF0000",
        name: 84
    }, {
        lat: "48.993723",
        lng: "-122.7471191",
        color: "#FF0000",
        name: 83
    }, {
        lat: "48.0795365",
        lng: "-123.1018438",
        color: "#FF0000",
        name: 82
    }, {
        lat: "45.62722589999999",
        lng: "-122.6727305",
        color: "#FF0000",
        name: 81
    }]
    var points = []
    var polylines = []

    function initMap() {
        // Create the map.
        var mapOptions = {
            center: {
                lat: 39.90419989999999,
                lng: 116.4073963
            },
            zoom: 2

        };
        googleMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), mapOptions);
    }

    /**
     * Clears markers and directions from the map.
     */
    var clearMap = function() {
        while (markers.length > 0) {
            markers.pop().setMap(null);
        }
        clearMapDirections();
    };

    /**
     * Clears the directions from the map.
     */
    var clearMapDirections = function() {
        while (polylines.length > 0) {
            polylines.pop().setMap(null);
        }

    };
    var showMapMarkers = function(points) {
        // clear map
        clearMap();

        var mapPosition;
        // add points and compute bounds
        mapBounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            var pointData = points[i];
            mapPosition = new window.google.maps.LatLng(pointData.lat, pointData.lng);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {
                    lat: Number(pointData.lat),
                    lng: Number(pointData.lng)
                }
            })
            marker.setMap(googleMap);
            markers.push(marker);
            mapBounds.extend(mapPosition);
        }

        // calculate the center / bounds of the map view
        if (points.length === 1) {
            googleMap.setCenter(mapBounds.getCenter());
            googleMap.setZoom(10);
        } else {
            googleMap.fitBounds(mapBounds);
        }
        routeAndDisplayDirections(points)
    };
    /*
     * Polyline
     */
    var routeAndDisplayDirections = function(points) {

        if (points.length > 1) {
            // render a route for the points

            var gmapPoints = [];
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                gmapPoints.push(new window.google.maps.LatLng(points[i].lat, points[i].lng));
            }
            var lines = new window.google.maps.Polyline({
                path: gmapPoints,
                geodesic: true,
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 0.57,
                strokeWeight: 4
            });
            lines.setMap(googleMap);
            if (googleMap === googleMap) {
                polylines.push(lines);
            }
        }
    }

    $("#btn1").on("click", function() {
        showMapMarkers(point1)
    })
    $("#btn2").on("click", function() {
        showMapMarkers(point2)
    })
    $("#btn3").on("click", function() {
        showMapMarkers(point3)
    })
```